# What should be better approach, MPMoviePlayerController or AVFoundation

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

I want to make a player that can play local video file as well as HTTP Stream, the player should have customize ui controls, a subtitle rendered manually on top of video screen, custom content with transparent background display on top of player.

What should be easier approach for me to implement such the player, MPMoviePlayerController or AV Foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to show subtitle, its better to use `AVPlayer`,
Unfortunately this feature is missing in the MPMoviePlayer playback classes. This is obviously rather annoying, and you should consider filing a feature request with Apple. You can use the `AVPlayer` class instead, which as a `.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled` property: the downside is it's somewhat more complicated to use and only available on iOS 4.0+.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with MPMoviePlayerController. It's a little higher level, so it takes less work to implement.

MPMoviePlayerController offers a UIView that will display the video, and you can add any content you like into this view. Docs say:

```
You can add subviews to the view in this property. You might do this
in cases where you want to display custom playback controls or add
other custom content that is relevant to your app.
```

You can also use the MPMoviePlayerViewController to display the view if you like, or just add the view to one of your existing views.

It will display controls for you, but you can easily turn this feature off and display your own custom controls instead. You'd have to do that with AVPlayer, since it doesn't offer any user controls.

I'm not sure what @MilKyWaY means by "Since you need to show subtitle, its better to use AVPlayer, Unfortunately this feature is missing in the MPMoviePlayer playback classes." That's just what MPMoviePlayerController's view property is for. AVPlayer doesn't offer anything better for displaying custom labels, although you can do that with it too.

Comment: If by "subtitle" you mean closed captioning, both AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController can display subtitles. You can turn this on and off in code with AVPlayer. With MPMoviePlayerController, the user turns this on and off in the Settings app.

Comment: yes, i meant closed captioning. Both `AVPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayerController` support displaying closed caption. The later does make my solution simpler, but in full screen mode, `MPMoviePlayerController` does not show the customized view that i added

Comment: Unfortunately, MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated in iOS 9.